# Unable to load class 'org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook'

Tags: apache-poi

I am facing Unable to load class 'org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook'.
error during run time.

I added below dependencies in gradle file. code built successfully. But during runtime i face Unable to load class 'org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook'.

```
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2'
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '2.3.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-examples', version: '5.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20'

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.0.0'

implementation group: 'com.github.virtuald', name: 'curvesapi', version: '1.06'
implementation group: 'de.rototor.pdfbox', name: 'graphics2d', version: '0.31'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.20'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-lite', version: '5.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.santuario', name: 'xmlsec', version: '2.2.1'
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-all', version: '1.14', ext: 'pom'
implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on', version: '1.68'

testImplementation group: 'junitperf', name: 'junitperf', version: '1.8'    
implementation group: 'stax', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0'
implementation group: 'xalan', name: 'xalan', version: '2.7.2'
implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.1'
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: the schemas are now called poi-ooxml-full:5.0.0 or poi-ooxml-lite:5.0.0. so remove ooxml-schemas and ooxml-examples. maybe the "unable to load..." results from that invalid dependency. actually the lite schema should be picked up automatically ... so if you don't need the full schema, omit it. otherwise excluded the lite schema

Comment: removed schemas, example and oo-xml-lite. Still same issue can be seen

Comment: I've just seen this totally outdated reference. remove the XmlBeans reference, it comes transitively with ooxml. I would remove all your references except poi-ooxml and then add the missing ones. gradle does a good job in retrieving the transitive dependencies

Comment: I did the same. During run time still facing unable load class error